# Laravel 5.4 custom Auth::attempt always return false even my credential is true

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I try to create auth::guard('profile') and using profiles table and Profile model but when I tried to do Auth::attempt($credential) it's always returning false even if my credentials is true.

Migration

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateProfilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('ProfileID');
            $table->string('Name');
            $table->string('UserId')->unique();
            $table->string('Email')->unique();
            $table->string('Password');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('profiles');
    }
}
```

Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


class Profile extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable =
    [
        'Name', 'UserId', 'Email', 'Password'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $hidden =
    [
        'Password'
    ];
}
```

config\auth.php

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'profile' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'profiles'
        ]
    ],   

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'profiles' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Profile::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

ProfileController

```
public function postLogin(Request $r){
        $credential = array(
            'UserId' => $r->input('UserId'),
            'Password' => $r->input('Password')
        );

        if(Auth::guard('profile')->attempt($credential)) {
          echo "success";
        }else{
            Session::flash('error', 'Username or password is incorect');
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

Please help me, I cant find where the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried to hard code a login instead of using user input creds to make sure auth is working? Like this: Auth::loginUsingId(1);

Comment: you mean like this if(Auth::guard('profile')->attempt(['UserId' => $r->input('UserId'), 'Password' => $r->input('Password') ])) I've tried that but still didn't work

Comment: Instead of attempt(), you can hard code a login for testing.  Something like `Auth::guard('profile')->loginUsingId(1)`   to manually login profile user that has id of 1.

Comment: But how to validate the password? My password is encrypted. Is it possible?

Comment: Check if your password is encrypted or plain in the the database, it should be encrypted

Comment: [SOLVED] change 'Password' on credential into 'password' then adding public function getAuthPassword() { return $this->Password } into Profile model. I dont know why but it's work